# adjusting form for any resolution

Tags: vb.net

i have made 3 projects in vb.net.for all those three projects i have used this code

```
 Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
```

my laptop resolution is 1366x768.for my resolution i'm getting the desired output but for any other resolution i'm finding the objects being misplaced.

is there any way by which i can make my forms adjust for any particular resolution.

Comment: Do you have any examples of what you mean? This could simply be a design issue where you need to implement appropriate panels, docking, and anchors for your controls.

Answer (score 0):

Play around with docking and anchoring on your controls. This is what those are meant for. Alternatively, just disable the `Locked` property of your form. Doing this means that the form cannot be resized.